# How to extract the contents inside a div based on its class?

Tags: php, html, dom

I tried with this code,

```
$html= file_get_contents("page.html");
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$div = $dom->getElementsByClassName('mydiv1');
$result = $dom->saveHTML($div);
echo $result;
```

### page.html

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="test">
<div class="mydiv1">Hello</div>
<div class="mydiv2">How are you</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I tried with Id its works. like,

```
$html= file_get_contents("page.html");
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$div = $dom->getElementById('test');
$result = $dom->saveHTML($div);
echo $result;
```

How can I get the content based on class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code,

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$div = $xpath->query('//div[@class="mydiv1"]');
$div = $div->item(0);
$result = $dom->saveXML($div);
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no actual `getElementsByClassName` (yet) in `DOMDocument`, but the same results can be produced using `DOMXpath` as :

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->load($filePath);
$finder = new DomXPath($dom);
$nodes= $finder->query('//div[@class="mydiv1"]');
```